# React Router parameters not working

Tags: reactjs, parameters, react-router

I have some problems with the React router parameters. In other words, I can't get the parameters to work. This is how I have set it up, and it's literally driving me crazy - as I have tried everything and I can't seem to get it to work.

Code:

```
    const websiteRoutes = (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Index} exact={true}/>
            <Route path="/admin" component={Admin}/>
            <Route path="/admin_panel" component={AdminPanel}/>
            <Route path="/message/id/:id" component={ReadMessage}/>
            <Route path="/sitemap.xml"/>
            <Route path="/robots.txt"/> 
        </Switch>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

And I tried this as well:

```
const websiteRoutes = (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Index} exact={true}/>
            <Route path="/admin" component={Admin}/>
            <Route path="/admin_panel" component={AdminPanel}/>
            <Route path="/message/id" component={ReadMessage}>
            <Route path="/:id" component={ReadMessage}>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/sitemap.xml"/>
            <Route path="/robots.txt"/> 
        </Switch>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

I am desperately trying to make my URL look like this, as I am trying to create a website in order to show messages that has been sent to me. Formatted like this: 'http://myurl.com/message/id/485'. How can I do this?

Comment: what is happening when you navigate to '/message/id/485' with first code snippet? getting any error?

Comment: @MayankShukla I get this in my console: [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (bundle.js, line 0).

Comment: Are you using webpack dev server? If so, try setting `devServer.historyApiFallback` to true in your webpack config.

Comment: @kLabz Yes I am using webpack dev server, and I have already tried that - so it doesn't make an impact :-(

Comment: Ok. Your routes look fine (in your first snippet anyway). Are you sure there is nothing wrong with `ReadMessage`?

Comment: @kLabz That's the thing - if I set my route to just '/message' it works perfectly. But if I add another slash and make it just '/message/id' it gives me an error. Truly strange, and by the way - the params does work if I set my url to just '/:id' also.

Comment: You need url rewriting so that whatever unresolved url goes to your index.html This is taken care of by webpack dev server when you are developing your app and test it via http://localhost:9000 (or some other port), but if you're not then you need to configure apache or nginx.

Comment: @kLabz how do I change the port?

Comment: Can you make a codesandbox to depict your issue, your code looks fine btw

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri What do you want to look at? I'll send everything that's necessary.

Comment: @askaale Did you ever figure this out?  I am running into the same issue.

Comment: @Shawn Hi Shawn. I did find a way to bypass it, and that was to use the 'create-react-app' through console, instead of setting up my React project manually. However - I am not sure how to fix this in any other way, I'm sorry.

Comment: @askaale Thanks for following that up, I also found out how to solve the issue I was having as the marked answer suggests here in my posts if you are curious still if that will work for you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824582/react-router-dom-browserrouter-not-navigating-to-paths-with-more-than-one-url-pa

Comment: [Try to do something like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54768059/6464720)