# react-router-dom BrowserRouter not navigating to paths with more than one url parameter

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-router-dom, webpack-4

I am having an issue where I am not able to navigate to Routes with paths greater than 1 section like so when using `react-router-dom@4.2.2`:  In addition, this is the Github link to the repo where I am having this issue.

https://github.com/ShawnCholeva/React-Typescript-Webpack4-Router

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
//All routes work if I use HashRouter here instead of BrowserRouter

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={ Login }/> <--- Works
                    <Route exact path='/accountSetup/:guid?' component={ AccountSetup }/> 
                    ^-- Above works when just '/accountSetup' but fails when I do '/accountSetup/123'
                    <Route component={ NotFound } /> <--- Works
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

So I noticed this is only working when I use HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter.  So that led me to think it may be how I am serving the application via `webpack-dev-server@3.1.1`.  So I saw that I had to add historyApiFallback property to my devServer properties object using `webpack@4.2.0` like so:

```
devServer: {
    compress: true,
    port: 8080,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname),
    publicPath: '/',
}
```

And then I run the application through a npm script in my package.json that looks like this:

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development"
```

So when I navigate to localhost:5000/accountSetup/123 I get the following error in the console:

[image]

I have also tried to serve this with the `http-server-spa` package and noticed the following log when navigating:

```
[OK] Serving static files from ./dist
[OK] Using the fallback file index.html
[OK] Listening on http://localhost:8080
----------------------------------------------
[OK] GET /accountSetup
[OK] GET /bundle.js
[OK] GET /accountSetup/123
[ER] GET /accountSetup/bundle.js
```

It seems like it is adding the prefix in the url of the last route parameter to the route loading bundle.js.  So you can see when I navigated to accountSetup, it just referenced bundle.js because it the last segment in the url.  But when I add multiple segments, it seems to append the prior segments from localhost to the last segment, to the path of bundle.js

EDIT:

Seems to be something in regards to BrowserRouter using dynamic routing vs HashRouter using static routing.

This is my full package.json and webpack.config.js files

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-webpack4-typescript-skeleton",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React application using Webpack 4 and Typescript",
  "main": "index.tsx",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
    "prestart": "npm run test",
    "build:prod": "webpack --mode production --config webpack.config.js",
    "lint": "tslint 'src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'",
    "test": "jest",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "build:docker": "docker-compose up --build -d"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "React",
    "Webpack 4",
    "Typescript"
  ],
  "author": "Shawn Choleva",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^22.2.2",
    "@types/react": "^16.0.41",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.4",
    "@types/react-redux": "^5.0.15",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.2.5",
    "@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
    "@types/webpack": "^4.1.2",
    "@types/webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.0",
    "jest": "^22.4.3",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "ts-jest": "^22.4.2",
    "ts-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "tslint-react": "^3.5.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "less": "^3.0.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/tests/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

const config = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
             }
          },
          {
            loader: "less-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      { 
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        use:'url-loader' 
      },
      { 
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "url-loader",
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]',
            },
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.ts', '.tsx', '.js' ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'Application Name',
        template: path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.html')
    })
  ],
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    compress: true,
    port: 8080,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname),
    publicPath: '/',
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: In your example "/accountSetup" and "/accountSetup/test" reference the same component. How do you know that "/accountSetup/test" is not working?

Comment: It shows the above error image, that I posted after the npm start script, when I navigate to that url...  and if I switch BrowserRouter out with HashRouter it works as expected.  Only an issue with BrowserRouter, which is what I'm trying to get working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I have found the issue. The `publicPath` was missing in your webpack configuration. Here is the updated output config:

```
output: {
   filename: 'bundle.js',
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
   publicPath: '/' <-- ADDED THIS
  },
```

Comment: That was it!  Will mark as answer, any explanation as to why publicPath is necessary in output?

Comment: Also can't award bounty for another 16 hours but will do tomorrow

Comment: Sure Thanks, @Shawn. @RickyM has given a very nice explanation on the importance of the `publicPath`. You can read that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48054492/5284640

Comment: I'm using react-router-dom v6 and I tried your solution but nothing has changed

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to make a nested route. But in ReactRouter v4 which as you point out uses dynamic routing nested routes should be nested inside the component. Meaning in your `AccountSetup` render method you should add.

```
render(){
 //...
  <Route
    path={match.url + '/test'}
    component={Test}
  />
// ...
}
```

Read more about nested routes in the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/philosophy/nested-routes). Here is a [live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-dom-4-nested-example?file=index.js).
If you do want to use static routes instead you can [try this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/static-routes).

Comment: I updated my question to show what I am trying to do more accurately as the above example was poor. The goal is trying to pass in a url parameter to the about path (which now is an optional guid param), that renders the same error as the earlier one of /about/test.   I went to the documents you provided and the nested components don't seem to fit as I would only want to render one component and not two seperate.  That static route link is interesting though as it seems webpack-dev-server tries to host static files.

Comment: I will try and look into the static page and see if I can find some form of resolution from that.  Worst case if that is the issue, I will either just use HashRouter or downgrade to a v3 router.  It would be nice though if there is in fact a way to serve these files with BrowserRouter without the extra setup, but I am not sure if webpack-dev-server is able to host this.